# Can i get all items of all content types within a site collection using search API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

I want to show all Created BY and Modified BY users of all items of all content types within a site collection. Currently I'm using the

*_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refiners='owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo'&selectproperties='CreatedBy,ModifiedBy*'

it is not returning all results. Is there any API to get all items of all content types ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

(Moved the * to the beginning and added contenttype as selected property)

https://Yourtenant.sharepoint.com/Search/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refiners='owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo'&selectproperties='CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,Contenttype'

This is an extremely wide query. What do you mean by "All Items" exactly? You need all items in your tenant or only from a single site?

Comment: Thanks for the response. like for example we can use document library and list items content types "ContentClass:STS_ListItem+ContentClass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary". So is there any way to get all content types instead of mentioned everything in the query. ?

Comment: So your goal is to retrieve all content types and not all items for them?

Comment: Not exactly, using these  all content types i have to retrieve items ( content ) 'Created BY' and 'Modified By' user names. Just i want to display who is the top participant in that particular site collection. Like whole involved more in creating and modifying items

Comment: Ok, scoped by Sitecollection. I don't think search might be the right tool then. The I would check the audit log or the site changes during a certain duration for that. There is no reason to filter by CT first I guess